# Powershell Shutdown VM Script

Tags: powershell

I have a script that can shutdown vms based on names entered into an array.

That part works fine, but the next part after the shutdown initiates is supposed to wait for a period and notify how many vms it is waiting to shut down before it moves on to another phase of shutting down other vms.

I am not getting any vms counted out of the array. Here is the code for a particular phase:

```
$waittime = 5 #Seconds

#Create Phase 1 Array
[Array] $PHASE1 = "TestSvr2008"

# For each of the VMs on the Hyperv hosts that are powered on
Foreach ($VM in ($PHASE1 | %{ Get-VM | Where { $_.State -eq "Running" }})){
    # Shutdown the guest cleanly
    $VM | Stop-VM -Confirm:$false }

    # Set the amount of time to wait before assuming the remaining powered on guests are stuck
$waittime = 120 #Seconds

$Time = (Get-Date).TimeofDay
do {
    # Wait for the VMs to be Shutdown cleanly
    sleep 1.0
    $timeleft = $waittime - ($Newtime.seconds)
    $numvms = ($PHASE1 | %{ Get-VM | Where { $_.$VM -eq $PHASE1 }}).Count
    Write "Waiting for shutdown of $numvms VMs or until $timeleft seconds"
    $Newtime = (Get-Date).TimeofDay - $Time
    } until ((@($PHASE1 | %{ Get-VM | Where { $_.$VM -eq $PHASE1 }}).Count) -eq 0 -or ($Newtime).Seconds -ge $waittime)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This line in `do` and `until` blocks has issues:

```
$numvms = ($PHASE1 | %{ Get-VM | Where { $_.$VM -eq $PHASE1 }}).Count
```

- `$_.$VM` is typo, it should be `$_.VM`
- `$_.VM -eq $PHASE1` tries to check if VM name is equal to array. Comparisons do not work that way.
- `ForeEach-Object` is unnecessary

[Get-Vm](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848479.aspx) accepts array of VM names by pipeline or directly as `Name` parameter. So you can do this:

```
$numvms = ($PHASE1 | Get-VM).Count
```

or

```
$numvms = (Get-VM -Name $PHASE1).Count
```

Comment: Thanks! Ill give it a go

Comment: Ok new problem, if i have more than one vm, and the name of the vm is not in the array, the vm is still getting shut down, any ideas?